# I want to create a color picker in ionic app

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic4, color-picker

In my app I want to create a color list whenever I choose a color from that list in the next field color of my text is automatically change according to that list. I don't have any code.

Comment: Please provide what you have done so far, Stackoverflow is not the place where you  will get project development from community. __I don't have any code.__ this never should be the case. First you need to try out stuff and if something is not working or you are struck somewhere then you should ask question on SO.

Answer (score 3):

here is [example for you](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-color-picker-6h9vfn?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Credit for https://stackblitz.com/@bockoblur

import

```
import { ColorPickerModule } from 'ngx-color-picker';

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ColorPickerModule
  ]
})
```

.html

```
<input 
      [style.background]="colorList[0].value" 
      [(colorPicker)]="colorList[0].value"
      [cpOKButton] = "true"
      [cpOKButtonText] = "'Select'"
      [cpCancelButton] = "true"
      [cpSaveClickOutside] = "'false'"
      [cpDisableInput]="false"
      [cpAlphaChannel]="'disabled'" 
      [cpOutputFormat]="'hex'"
      [cpPresetColors]="presetValues"
      [cpAddColorButton]="true" 
  />
```

Comment: I might be wrong but isn't this solution only apply if Angular is being used? Would this work for React or Vue with Ionic?